# C++ performance advice for memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management

GOAL: I have a question about performances on a Microsoft Windows console application in C++ that deals with processing data frames received from a serial com port.
In C and embedded system (which I have most of my experience) I usually allocate large buffers at compile time.
But since what I am working on right now is a software that manages a serial com port using a logical protocol that will run on windows (a upper layer software will interact with this in order to communicate with embedded systems connected in a serial bus), and RAM and CPU speeds are not an issue, I am taking advantages of objects capability of C++.

MY SOLUTION: So what I am doing is, when I receive a data frame, I have a class that can store all the information like frame type (ack response, nack responce, ack request etc.), source and destination node address, and payloads (which I am dynamically allocating buffers of dynamic length from 0 to 1024 bytes).
What I am doing at the moment is, I have a compile time allocated buffer of 5 bytes that stores the header inside the class that handles the protocol. Once I receive a complete 5 bytes header, I use the payload size field to allocating a buffer needed to store the payload, onece the full frame is received, I calculate the crc16 and validate the data to be valid, and if true, I am than creating a frame class object that will store all the information plus the pointer to the allocated buffer storing the payload (so no copy is ever needed), then pass the packet object to the layer above for more processing, what ever, also the frame object destructor will de-allocate the buffer storing the payload once the frame object is deleted from the above layers of the software.
Is that a good approach, or I am killing the PC performance. TX scheduling is done is a similar way.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is fine. Allocating buffers at runtime is not considered bad practice if the sizes aren't known at compile time. It also looks like you're taking care to not copy the buffers around unnecessarily, which is good practice.

If you're worried about performance, you can try a 3rd party allocater such as TCMalloc or JEMalloc, although these usually help more with heavily threaded or fragmented memory spaces.

If these buffers are generally similar sizes, and are constantly allocated and deallocated, you can create a buffer pool at initialization, and request / return them to / from the pool during runtime rather than calling new/delete.

Comment: (create a buffer pool at initialization, and request / return them to / from the pool during runtime rather than calling new/delete), this approach is what I am doing in the embedded side, because of the limited resources and CPU speeds. I was up to trying different approach on a PC since memory and CPU speed are not an issue. Dynamic allocation is kind of a new thing for me, and I was reading that it is really a bottle neck to performances. I was curios if that is a better way of doing it. What header file I need to include to try TCMalloc? any reference documentation? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Dominick First thing I would do is performance profile your code using something like gprof (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/). This will tell you if the allocation is really a bottleneck in your use case. TCMalloc is a drop in replacement for new/delete created by Google, you can check it out here (http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html)